# play unable to parse dependency versions

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, ivy

I am currently working on a play application as a front end developer. For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question I have moved development from mac to a windows machine. This is where my problems kick in (surprised?).

Most of our systems work well, but there is one very very stubborn issue that I have not been able to solve. it seems that dependency version are never parsed so that versions defined as **${version.org.codehaus.jackson}** stays ${version.org.codehaus.jackson} and is never resolved to its version number **1.9.2**

Our application has (too?) many dependencies.These dependencies are defines in ivysettings and then the whole thing magically gets build (we use sbt to manage this).

Now, I am a humble front end developer, so lots of the magic here are.. well magic. The back end team is starting to give up on me, and so am I, but apparently there is an issue where the versions are not parsed.

My end result is:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                                                                                           
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::                                                                                           
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                                                                                           
[warn]  :: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;${version.org.codehaus.jackson}: not found                                                    
[warn]  :: commons-configuration#commons-configuration;${version.commons-configuration}: not found                                               
[warn]  :: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;${version.org.codehaus.jackson}: not found                                                      
[warn]  :: org.hibernate#hibernate-core;${version.org.hibernate}: not found                                                                      
[warn]  :: commons-pool#commons-pool;${version.commons-pool}: not found                                                                          
[warn]  :: commons-io#commons-io;${version.commons-io}: not found                                                                                
[warn]  :: log4j#log4j;${version.log4j}: not found                                                                                               
[warn]  :: jline#jline;${version.jline}: not found                                                                                               
[warn]  :: commons-collections#commons-collections;${version.commons-collections}: not found                                                     
[warn]  :: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;${version.commons-beanutils}: not found                                                           
[warn]  :: dom4j#dom4j;${version.dom4j}: not found                                                                                               
[warn]  :: antlr#antlr;${version.antlr}: not found                                                                                               
[warn]  :: org.hornetq#hornetq-core;${version.org.hornetq}: not found                                                                            
[warn]  :: org.hornetq#hornetq-jms;${version.org.hornetq}: not found                                                                             
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                                                                                           
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.                                                                           
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;${version.org.codehaus.jackson}: not found
```

I understand this is not enough to understand the issue completely. But there is no problem with the project, it compiles without any problems on my mac, but not on my windows machine. the versions stay as **${version.org.whatever}** instead of being parsed into beautiful versions.

Play 2.2.2 and sbt (0.13 i think) is installed as well as a working java jdk. Other projects based on roughly the same code-base works as well..

Soo. Anyone can give me a nudge in the right direction? I am clueless now, is there a way to step in to the version resolving or something to see what is going on?

Thanks to whoever finds time to look at this

Bård

edit: added my build.scala all values in [] have been removed intentionally

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._


object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "[myApp"
  val appVersion = "1.5-SNAPSHOT"
  val solrsearchVersion = "4.4-SNAPSHOT"
  val syndicationVersion = "1.15-SNAPSHOT";
  val playCommonsVersion = "0.1-SNAPSHOT";
  val nexusDomain = "[myNexus]"
  val nexusWimp = "http://" + nexusDomain + "[nexuspath]"


  val appDependencies = Seq(

    // PLAY MODULES
    javaCore,
    javaEbean,


    "[mycompany]" %% "play-commons" % playCommonsVersion,
    "[mycompany].syndication" % "syndication-api" % syndicationVersion,
    "[mycompany].syndication.user" % "user-api" % syndicationVersion,
    "[mycompany].syndication.playlist" % "playlist-api" % syndicationVersion,
    "[mycompany].syndication" % "syndication-client" % syndicationVersion,
    "[mycompany].system.solrsearch" % "solrsearch-api" % solrsearchVersion,

    "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "15.0",
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3"

  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(

    organization := "[mycompany]",

    credentials += Credentials("Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager", nexusDomain, "[username]", "[password]"),

    resolvers := Seq(

      // LOCAL
      "Local Maven" at "file://" + Path.userHome.absolutePath + "/.m2/repository",

      // TYPESAFE
      "Typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",

      // [myCompany]
      "[myCompany] nexus repository" at nexusWimp

    ),

    publishTo := {
      Some("[myCompany] nexus repos" at nexusWimp)
    }


  )

  val printWriter = new java.io.PrintWriter(new File("VERSION"))
```

Comment: Could you provide the content of your build file ? It should be either a `build.sbt` file at the root of the project or a `Build.scala` under the `project` directory.

Comment: Thanks for taking the interest. Added the build.scala in original post.

Comment: Kind of a long shot, but you could add `logLevel := Level.Debug` to `project/plugins.sbt`, and compare the messages (after doing `clean`) between the Mac and Windows version. If all else fails, work in a VM!

Comment: Thanks, that nudged me in the right direction.. I hope. Seems there is an issue with the ivy dependencies, since the projects that work are all maven projects.. I'll post, but you gave me hope.